# Tikz cross not showing, just an outline box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to overlay a cross on a png using tikz. However, instead of a cross being produced, only a thin square outline box is being shown.

The code I have used is shown here:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] (tc99) at (0,6) {\Large Isotope to Trace};
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Photos/coN_99tc.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[blue,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.58,0.67) rectangle (0.67,0.50);
        \draw [-latex, ultra thick, blue] (tc99) to[out=0, in=120] (0.60,0.68);
        \node [cross out,draw=red] at (0.55,0.55) {};
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I'm using overleaf to compile a beamer presentation if this makes a difference

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete, self contained document which we can test as it is.

Comment: @user121799 You can use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}` in Overleaf without any problem.

Comment: @Allentro Could you please add a sketch of what should be the final result?